# how to display the selected text instead of values

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i have a piece of code & i couldn't display the selected text instead of values in fourth list box. Now, It displays the values of the option but i want to display the text i.e Paper Manufacturers <<  Paper Converters << Molded Pulp Products.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var firstCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category';
  var secondCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category1';
  var thirdCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category2';
  var firstCategory = $(firstCategorySelector);
  var secondCategory = $(secondCategorySelector);
  var thirdCategory = $(thirdCategorySelector);
  var addCategoryButton = $("#add-category");
  var removeCategoryButton = $('#remove-category');
  var selectedList = $('#selected-lst-values');
  var choice = $("#tget");
  $('.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2').change(function() {
    AddCategoryButtonEnable();
  });

  function getCategoryValues() {
    var firstCategoryValue = firstCategory.val();
    var secondCategoryValue = secondCategory.val();
    var thirdCategoryValue = thirdCategory.val();
    return [firstCategoryValue, secondCategoryValue, thirdCategoryValue];
  }

  function isDisableAddButton() {
    var values = getCategoryValues();
    return (!values[0] || !values[1] || !values[2]);
  }

  function AddCategoryButtonEnable() {
    var isDisableAddCategoryButton = isDisableAddButton();
    addCategoryButton.prop("disabled", isDisableAddCategoryButton).toggleClass('text-bold', isDisableAddCategoryButton);
  }

  function getNumberOfSelectedOption() {
    return selectedList.find("option").length;
  }

  function getAvailableChoice() {
    return 20 - parseInt(getNumberOfSelectedOption());
  }

  function setAvailableChoice($numChoice) {
    var strText = ($numChoice !== 20) ? $numChoice + " more " : "up to 20 ";
      choice.text(strText);
  }

  function appendChoice() {
      var count="";
      var givenCategoryArrayValue = getCategoryValues();
      if ($('#selected-lst-values option:contains("' + givenCategoryArrayValue[0] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[1] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[2] + '")').length > 0) {alert('This category has already been added.');
      return count=1;
    }
      else {
        selectedList.append('<option value="'+ givenCategoryArrayValue[0] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[1] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[2] +'">' + givenCategoryArrayValue[0] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[1] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[2] + '</option>');
        return count=2;
             }
    }
  addCategoryButton.click(function() {
      var availableChoice = getAvailableChoice();
      if (availableChoice >= 1) {
        var a=appendChoice();
        if(a==2){
        setAvailableChoice(availableChoice - 1);
        }
      } else {
        setAvailableChoice(0);
      }
    });
    var option = selectedList.find('option:selected');
    selectedList.change(function() {
      removeCategoryButton.prop("disabled", false);
      addCategoryButton.prop("disabled", true);
      _addRemoveButtonClickListener();
    });

  function _addRemoveButtonClickListener() {
      removeCategoryButton.click(function() {
        selectedList.find('option:selected').remove();
        var availableChoice = getAvailableChoice();
        if (0 < availableChoice < 6) {
          setAvailableChoice(availableChoice);
        } else {
          setAvailableChoice(0);
        }
        removeCategoryButton.prop("disabled", true);
      });
    }
});
```

```css
.select-manage-category,
.select-manage-category1,
.select-manage-category2 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
p {
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#selected-lst-values {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
    <option value="1">Paper Manufacturers</option>
    <option value="2">Paper Products Suppliers</option>
    <option value="3">Paper Chemicals Suppliers</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
    <option value="1">Paper Converters</option>
    <option value="2">Lab Apparatus & Supplies</option>
    <option value="3">Service Providers</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
    <option value="1">Molded Pulp Products</option>
    <option value="2">Software Vendors</option>
    <option value="3">Information Services</option>
  </select>
</div>
<p style="padding-top:10px;color:red;">You can add <span id="target">up to 5</span> categories</p>
</div>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category" disabled="true">
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category" disabled="true">
<div>
  <select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="7" multiple="multiple">
  </select>
</div>
<button id="mnage-category-savebtn" class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button">
  <strong>Save Categories</strong>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Is all of that code necessary for this question? Is the CSS event relevant at all?

Comment: Aren't you getting `.value` somewhere instead of `.text`? There's way too much code here for me to figure out what you're appending where.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign these texts which you want to get as the value of each options:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var firstCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category';
 var secondCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category1';
 var thirdCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category2';
 var firstCategory = $(firstCategorySelector);
 var secondCategory = $(secondCategorySelector);
 var thirdCategory = $(thirdCategorySelector);
 var addCategoryButton = $("#add-category");
 var removeCategoryButton = $('#remove-category');
 var selectedList = $('#selected-lst-values');
 var choice = $("#tget");
 $('.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2').change(function() {
  AddCategoryButtonEnable();
 });

 function getCategoryValues() {
  var firstCategoryValue = firstCategory.val();
  var secondCategoryValue = secondCategory.val();
  var thirdCategoryValue = thirdCategory.val();
  return [firstCategoryValue, secondCategoryValue, thirdCategoryValue];
 }
   function getCategoryDisplay() {
  var firstCategoryDisplay = $(firstCategorySelector+" option:selected").text();
  var secondCategoryDisplay = $(secondCategorySelector+" option:selected").text();
  var thirdCategoryDisplay = $(thirdCategorySelector+" option:selected").text();
  return [firstCategoryDisplay, secondCategoryDisplay, thirdCategoryDisplay];
 }

 function isDisableAddButton() {
  var values = getCategoryValues();
  return (!values[0] || !values[1] || !values[2]);
 }

 function AddCategoryButtonEnable() {
  var isDisableAddCategoryButton = isDisableAddButton();
  addCategoryButton.prop("disabled", isDisableAddCategoryButton).toggleClass('text-bold', isDisableAddCategoryButton);
 }

 function getNumberOfSelectedOption() {
  return selectedList.find("option").length;
 }

 function getAvailableChoice() {
  return 20 - parseInt(getNumberOfSelectedOption());
 }

 function setAvailableChoice($numChoice) {
  var strText = ($numChoice !== 20) ? $numChoice + " more " : "up to 20 ";
   choice.text(strText);
 }

 function appendChoice() {
   var count="";
   var givenCategoryArrayValue = getCategoryValues();
      var givenCategoryArrayDisplay = getCategoryDisplay();
   if ($('#selected-lst-values option:contains("' + givenCategoryArrayDisplay[0] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayDisplay[1] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayDisplay[2] + '")').length > 0) {alert('This category has already been added.');
   return count=1;
  }
   else {
    selectedList.append('<option value="'+ givenCategoryArrayValue[0] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[1] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[2] +'">' + givenCategoryArrayDisplay[0] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayDisplay[1] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayDisplay[2] + '</option>');
      return count=2;
           }
  }
 addCategoryButton.click(function() {
   var availableChoice = getAvailableChoice();
   if (availableChoice >= 1) {
    var a=appendChoice();
    if(a==2){
    setAvailableChoice(availableChoice - 1);
    }
   } else {
    setAvailableChoice(0);
   }
  });
  var option = selectedList.find('option:selected');
  selectedList.change(function() {
   removeCategoryButton.prop("disabled", false);
   addCategoryButton.prop("disabled", true);
   _addRemoveButtonClickListener();
  });

 function _addRemoveButtonClickListener() {
   removeCategoryButton.click(function() {
    selectedList.find('option:selected').remove();
    var availableChoice = getAvailableChoice();
    if (0 < availableChoice < 6) {
     setAvailableChoice(availableChoice);
    } else {
     setAvailableChoice(0);
    }
    removeCategoryButton.prop("disabled", true);
   });
  }
 });
```

```css
.select-manage-category,
.select-manage-category1,
.select-manage-category2 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

p {
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#selected-lst-values {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
  <option value="1">Paper Manufacturers</option>
  <option value="2">Paper Products Suppliers</option>
  <option value="3">Paper Chemicals Suppliers</option>
 </select></div>

 <div><select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
  <option value="1">Paper Converters</option>
  <option value="2">Lab Apparatus & Supplies</option>
  <option value="3">Service Providers</option>
 </select></div>
 <div><select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
  <option value="1">Molded Pulp Products</option>
  <option value="2">Software Vendors</option>
  <option value="3">Information Services</option>
 </select>
</div>
<p style="padding-top:10px;color:red;">You can add <span id="target">up to 5</span> categories</p>
</div>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category" disabled="true">
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category" disabled="true">
<div><select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="7" multiple="multiple">
</select></div>
<button id="mnage-category-savebtn" class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button"><strong>Save Categories</strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span></button>
```

Updated: Defined new function `getCategoryDisplay`  to get `text` of selected option as per your expected output in below comment.

Comment: Thank you :) But, i want to pass both values and text. i.e after selection the html code would be like this <option value="1 << 1 << 1">Paper Manufacturers << Paper Converters << Molded Pulp Products</option>

Comment: I have edit my answer as your expected outputs. please check it!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell how you want your final category data to be stored, but you can get the `option`s to hold text descriptions instead of numbers by creating a `getCategoryNames` function and using it in place of `getCategoryValues` in `appendChoice`:

```
function getCategoryNames() {
  return [].map.call(categories, function(e) {
    return $(':selected', e).text()
  })
}
```

It's also probably a good idea to give your `select`s a common class of `.select-manage-category` (without adding any numeric suffixes), because this simplifies your jQuery element selection:

```
var categories = $('.select-manage-category')
```

---

### Demo Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var categories = $('.select-manage-category')
  var addCategoryButton = $("#add-category")
  var removeCategoryButton = $('#remove-category')
  var selectedList = $('#selected-lst-values')
  var choice = $("#tget")

  categories.change(AddCategoryButtonEnable)

  function getCategoryValues() {
    return [].map.call(categories, function(e) {
      return e.value
    })
  }

  function getCategoryNames() {
    return [].map.call(categories, function(e) {
      return $(':selected', e).text()
    })
  }

  function isDisableAddButton() {
    var values = getCategoryValues();
    return (!values[0] || !values[1] || !values[2]);
  }

  function AddCategoryButtonEnable() {
    var isDisableAddCategoryButton = isDisableAddButton();
    addCategoryButton.prop("disabled", isDisableAddCategoryButton).toggleClass('text-bold', isDisableAddCategoryButton);
  }

  function getNumberOfSelectedOption() {
    return selectedList.find("option").length;
  }

  function getAvailableChoice() {
    return 20 - parseInt(getNumberOfSelectedOption());
  }

  function setAvailableChoice($numChoice) {
    var strText = ($numChoice !== 20) ? $numChoice + " more " : "up to 20 ";
    choice.text(strText);
  }

  function appendChoice() {
    var count = "";
    var givenCategoryArrayValue = getCategoryValues().join(' << ');
    if ($('#selected-lst-values option[value="' + givenCategoryArrayValue + '"]').length > 0) {
      alert('This category has already been added.');
      return count = 1;
    } else {
      selectedList.append(new Option(getCategoryNames().join(' << '), givenCategoryArrayValue));
      return count = 2;
    }
  }
  addCategoryButton.click(function() {
    var availableChoice = getAvailableChoice();
    if (availableChoice >= 1) {
      var a = appendChoice();
      if (a == 2) {
        setAvailableChoice(availableChoice - 1);
      }
    } else {
      setAvailableChoice(0);
    }
  });
  var option = selectedList.find(':selected');
  selectedList.change(function() {
    removeCategoryButton.prop("disabled", false);
    addCategoryButton.prop("disabled", true);
    _addRemoveButtonClickListener();
  });

  function _addRemoveButtonClickListener() {
    removeCategoryButton.click(function() {
      selectedList.find('option:selected').remove();
      var availableChoice = getAvailableChoice();
      if (0 < availableChoice < 6) {
        setAvailableChoice(availableChoice);
      } else {
        setAvailableChoice(0);
      }
      removeCategoryButton.prop("disabled", true);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.select-manage-category {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

p {
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#selected-lst-values {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
  <option value="1">Paper Manufacturers</option>
  <option value="2">Paper Products Suppliers</option>
  <option value="3">Paper Chemicals Suppliers</option>
 </select></div>

<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
  <option value="1">Paper Converters</option>
  <option value="2">Lab Apparatus &amp; Supplies</option>
  <option value="3">Service Providers</option>
 </select></div>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
  <option value="1">Molded Pulp Products</option>
  <option value="2">Software Vendors</option>
  <option value="3">Information Services</option>
 </select>
</div>
<p style="padding-top:10px;color:red;">You can add <span id="target">up to 5</span> categories</p>

<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category" disabled="true">
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category" disabled="true">
<div><select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="7" multiple="multiple">
</select></div>
<button id="mnage-category-savebtn" class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button"><strong>Save Categories</strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span></button>
```

Comment: Simple solution that's explained well.

Comment: Thank you :) But, i want to pass both values and text. i.e after selection the html code would be like this <option value="1 << 1 << 1">Paper Manufacturers << Paper Converters << Molded Pulp Products</option>

Comment: @alukkuthuni I updated the demo snippet; let me know if it works as expected :)

Comment: @alukkuthuni Have you had a chance to try out the snippet?

Answer (score 0):

`var firstCategoryValue = firstCategory.val();` will return the array of selected values.

To get the array of selected text use

```
$('.select-manage-category :selected').each(function(i, v) {
  firstCategoryValue[i] = $(v).text();
});
```

---

**Updated Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var firstCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category';
  var secondCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category1';
  var thirdCategorySelector = '.select-manage-category2';
  var firstCategory = $(firstCategorySelector);
  var secondCategory = $(secondCategorySelector);
  var thirdCategory = $(thirdCategorySelector);
  var addCategoryButton = $("#add-category");
  var removeCategoryButton = $('#remove-category');
  var selectedList = $('#selected-lst-values');
  var choice = $("#tget");
  $('.select-manage-category, .select-manage-category1, .select-manage-category2').change(function() {
    AddCategoryButtonEnable();
  });

  function getCategoryValues() {

    var firstCategoryValue = [];
    var secondCategoryValue = [];
    var thirdCategoryValue = [];
    $('.select-manage-category :selected').each(function(i, v) {
      firstCategoryValue[i] = $(v).text();
    });
    $('.select-manage-category1 :selected').each(function(i, v) {
      secondCategoryValue[i] = $(v).text();
    });
    $('.select-manage-category2 :selected').each(function(i, v) {
      thirdCategoryValue[i] = $(v).text();
    });
    return [firstCategoryValue, secondCategoryValue, thirdCategoryValue];
  }

  function isDisableAddButton() {
    var values = getCategoryValues();
    return (!values[0] || !values[1] || !values[2]);
  }

  function AddCategoryButtonEnable() {
    var isDisableAddCategoryButton = isDisableAddButton();
    addCategoryButton.prop("disabled", isDisableAddCategoryButton).toggleClass('text-bold', isDisableAddCategoryButton);
  }

  function getNumberOfSelectedOption() {
    return selectedList.find("option").length;
  }

  function getAvailableChoice() {
    return 20 - parseInt(getNumberOfSelectedOption());
  }

  function setAvailableChoice($numChoice) {
    var strText = ($numChoice !== 20) ? $numChoice + " more " : "up to 20 ";
    choice.text(strText);
  }

  function appendChoice() {
    var count = "";
    var givenCategoryArrayValue = getCategoryValues();
    if ($('#selected-lst-values option:contains("' + givenCategoryArrayValue[0] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[1] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[2] + '")').length > 0) {
      alert('This category has already been added.');
      return count = 1;
    } else {
      selectedList.append('<option value="' + givenCategoryArrayValue[0].value + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[1] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[2] + '">' + givenCategoryArrayValue[0] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[1] + ' << ' + givenCategoryArrayValue[2] + '</option>');
      return count = 2;
    }
  }
  addCategoryButton.click(function() {
    var availableChoice = getAvailableChoice();
    if (availableChoice >= 1) {
      var a = appendChoice();
      if (a == 2) {
        setAvailableChoice(availableChoice - 1);
      }
    } else {
      setAvailableChoice(0);
    }
  });
  var option = selectedList.find('option:selected');
  selectedList.change(function() {
    removeCategoryButton.prop("disabled", false);
    addCategoryButton.prop("disabled", true);
    _addRemoveButtonClickListener();
  });

  function _addRemoveButtonClickListener() {
    removeCategoryButton.click(function() {
      selectedList.find('option:selected').remove();
      var availableChoice = getAvailableChoice();
      if (0 < availableChoice < 6) {
        setAvailableChoice(availableChoice);
      } else {
        setAvailableChoice(0);
      }
      removeCategoryButton.prop("disabled", true);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.select-manage-category,
.select-manage-category1,
.select-manage-category2 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

p {
  clear: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#selected-lst-values {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category" size="5">
  <option value="1">Paper Manufacturers</option>
  <option value="2">Paper Products Suppliers</option>
  <option value="3">Paper Chemicals Suppliers</option>
 </select></div>

<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category1" size="5">
  <option value="1">Paper Converters</option>
  <option value="2">Lab Apparatus & Supplies</option>
  <option value="3">Service Providers</option>
 </select></div>
<div><select class="form-control select-manage-category2" size="5">
  <option value="1">Molded Pulp Products</option>
  <option value="2">Software Vendors</option>
  <option value="3">Information Services</option>
 </select>
</div>
<p style="padding-top:10px;color:red;">You can add <span id="target">up to 5</span> categories</p>
</div>
<input id="add-category" name="add" type="button" value="Add Category" disabled="true">
<input id="remove-category" name="add" type="button" value="Remove Category" disabled="true">
<div><select id="selected-lst-values" class="form-group percent-100" size="7" multiple="multiple">
</select></div>
<button id="mnage-category-savebtn" class="btn btn-md btn-radius pi-btn prodetails-btn" type="button"><strong>Save Categories</strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right right-arrow-head-icon"></span></button>
```